# Make images on website load slowly :)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to "simulate" the early web effect of slow loading images with javascript?

Something like this?

http://www.fugly.net/

Comment: I think your question is good, I don't understand downvotes

Comment: @Apolo This question is too broad and shows no research

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that for all the images?

For the main image is quite easy to do.

You can crate a hidden div, set the image as a background and then use slideDown with a really large value on document.ready();

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#yourdiv').slideDown(99999999);
});
```

:)

```
<div style='height: full height of the image'>
     <div id='yourdiv'>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a good answer but the BBox is updating with slideDown function so I would recomment to put #yourDiv inside a div with a fixed height

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is exactly what you're looking for, but I threw something together.

I wrapped the image in a div and put a div inside of it that will slowly reveal the image once every second.  I've randomized the number of pixels it will reveal at any given time so it looks a little more authentic.

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P9Pe5/)

Html:

```
<div class="container">
    <img id="flowerImage" src="http://i.imgur.com/xWVzyw9.jpg" />
    <div class="slowLoader"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#flowerImage{
    height: 300px;
}
.slowLoader{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: white;        
}
.container{
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){    
    var slowLoadHandler = setInterval(function(){        
        var currentHeight = parseInt($(".slowLoader").css("height"));        
        if(currentHeight <= 0){
            clearInterval(slowLoadHandler);
            return;
        }
        var changeHeight = getRandomArbitary(5,40);
        currentHeight = currentHeight - changeHeight;        
        $(".slowLoader").css("height", currentHeight);

    }, 1000);
});
function getRandomArbitary (min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Interersting approach!

Answer (score 0):

First of all; That is not an early web effect. That is causing by the size of the image and your internet connection speed and the hosting upload speed.

Anyway, if you want to have an effect like that, in theory you have to load the images first.

After each images loaded; you have to append and mask div and animate to bottom 0 frame by frame.

Basically for all images on your page:

CSS

```
img{
    opacity:0;
}

.wrap {
    height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

JS

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var $images = $('img');

  $images.each(function(){
    var $wrapper = $('<div />').addClass('wrap');

    $(this).wrap($wrapper);
    $(this).css('opacity', 1);

    $(this).parent().animate({
      height: '768px'
    }, 2000);
  });
});
```

Live JS:

http://jsbin.com/bemulehu/1/

Comment: Thx! Gonna try this one!